# How to fetch the difference in list using Ansible 'difference' filter?

Tags: filter, ansible, difference

I'm trying to fetch the difference in disk using the below Ansible playbook but `difference` filter is not fetching the difference:

```yaml
---
- name: Fetch the new disk
  hosts: servera.lab.example.com
  gather_facts: true

  tasks:

  - name: Output disk information before scanning
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'vd.*') | select('string') | list
    register: before_scan

  - name: Refresh facts
    ansible.builtin.setup:

  - name: Pause for 2 min to add the disk
    ansible.builtin.pause:
   
  - name: Output disk information after scanning
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'vd.*') | select('string') | list
    register: after_scan

  - name: Difference
    debug:
      msg: "{{ before_scal | difference(after_scan }}"
```

It is giving the below output

```json
TASK [Output disk information before scanning] *********************************
ok: [servera] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'vda') | select('string') | list": [
        "vda"
    ]
}

TASK [Refresh facts] ***********************************************************
ok: [servera]

TASK [Output disk information after scanning] **********************************
ok: [servera] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys() | map('regex_search', 'vd.*') | select('string') | list": [
        "vdb",
        "vda"
    ]
}

TASK [Difference] **************************************************************
fatal: [servera]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '}', expected ')'. String: {{ before_scal | difference(after_scan }}"}
```

Can you please help to correct the mistake in filtering, I need to fetch the `vdb` as the ouput of "TASK [Difference]".

Answer (score 0):

> *... `difference` filter is not fetching the difference ...*

According the documentation [`difference` filter – the difference of one list from another](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html), a minimal example playbook in order to

> *Provide a unique list of all the elements of the first list that do not appear in the second one.*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    BEFORE:
      - vda

    AFTER:
      - vda
      - vdb

  tasks:

  - name: Difference
    debug:
      msg: "{{ AFTER | difference(BEFORE) }}"
```

will result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [Difference] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - vdb
```

Please note the order `AFTER | difference(BEFORE)`.